# R - PNG has undesired vertical lines, plot doesn't

Tags: r, plot, png, cairo

I've been writing a plot to a png. The plot shows up fine on the screen, but when I PNG it, it has some random vertical lines in it.

Further notes -

1. I'm on windows 7, but using the "cairo-png" outputter. When I switch to "windows" outputter, the lines go away, but the background ceases to be transparent.
2. Changing the size of the png changes where the lines appear on it.

From RStudio PNG Export
[image: From RStudio PNG Export]
From PNG Source: 
[image: PNG from source]

---

Specific code:

```
png(file="RetirementRiskRecommendation.png", w=800,h=500,units="px",bg="transparent",family="Lato",type="cairo-png")
    par(mar=c(5,7.1,3,7.1),bty="n")
    barplot(t(as.matrix(other_aa[,-1])),space=0,border=NA,
            width=2,beside=FALSE,col=bmt_cols[c(1,8)],axes=FALSE,names.arg=rep("",length(other_times)))
    axis(1,at=xats,labels=xlabs,cex.axis=axis.cexer,las=1)
    axis(2,at=yats,labels=ylabs,cex.axis=axis.cexer,las=1)
    axis(4,at=yats,labels=ylabs,cex.axis=axis.cexer,las=1)
    #text(42,390000,label="Retirement (much more)",las=1,cex=text.cexer,pos=4,col=goal_cols[2])
    title(xlab="Time until goal",las=1,cex.lab=legend.cexer)
    title(main="General goal asset allocation over time",cex.main=legend.cexer, bty="n",col.main=bmt_cols[1],family="Lato")
    dev.off()
```

---

Comment: I really feel like I've seen this question before and that it has to do with the platform you are on and what png devices are available on that platform.

Comment: This plot should be saved as a vector graphic (pdf, eps, svg, wmf, take your choice).

Comment: Good point Joran. Note that I'm on windows 7, and I used the `cairo` device to create the PNG.

Comment: @Roland - this needs to be used on a webpage, and I've been told to use png.

Comment: Possibly tangential, but how did you get a 'barplot' to look like that?

Comment: @DWin - skillz to pay the billz...  check the barplot(t(matrix)) etc..

Comment: as a last resort you could try saving to a vector format and using ImageMagick/convert to make the PNG ... also, I'm unfamiliar with the Windows choices, but can you try the `Cairo` package (if you're not already using it)?

Comment: I can not check on my pc because `other_aa` is missing

Comment: @BenBolker I couldn't, but someone else could. But I'm trying to get these to be automatic, so that doesn't work well..

Comment: @Karsten W. that shouldn't matter much - the issue isn't the data - it's the "cairo" png.

Comment: I agree data is not the issue for your problem, but it is necessary to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: To my knowledge this happens when I have more data than pixels. Sometimes changing the dimensions of the png to higher values helps to alleviate this issue.